# Macro for compressing/expanding formulas in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, macros, macro-button

I have looked for a while but haven't come across something that does what I am looking for. I'm not that proficient in writing macros and if this isn't possible I will find a different solution to my problem

The basic premise is that I have a large formula that has many dependents. And those dependents have many dependence ect. I have forgoten how I made this and all I know is that it works.

I have tried using the evaluate formula tool and writing out the steps, but there are just too many.

My basic idea was to write a macro that will one of 2 things.

1. Remove all cell notations besides the 1 or 2 inputs, by replacing each dependent with the right formula.

If A1 had a formula and B1 used A1 in another formula. The mention of A1 in B1 would be replaced with the formula in A1. Ect.

The one or two inputs would be stated in the macro. These can be found when you update another cell and it changes the final answer.

2. Same method, but the final out come would either be the formula with just constants, or cells linked to constants.

It's kind of confusing and already giving me a headache thinking about it but if anyone can help that would be great.

Comment: please add the formula to your post, if it is not confidential

Comment: I'll see if I can add some of it however it is confidential. I was looking for something more universal but I have no clue if that's even possible

Comment: Writing a script to help you parse one formula doesn't seem worth it. I'm thinking you'll already end up spending more time just trying to identify various ranges, let alone substitute something for them. As a long shot maybe try to use one of those AI engines and ask it to interpret your formula. You may need to understand the concept of "prompt engineering". Good luck.